# Serialize into Datetime, Object

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson

I have map in this format,

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = {"RequestsServed":{"2019-06-28T00:00:00Z":0.0},"PullRequests":{"2019-06-28T00:00:00Z":0.0}}
```

My intension is to do `map.get("RequestsServed")` and get a map of
 `{"2019-06-28T00:00:00Z":0.0}` irrespective of number of key, value pair in it.

I tried using,

```
HashMap<DateTime, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(SerializationUtils.toJson(map.get("RequestsServed").toString()), HashMap.class);
```

and failed. please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the `class` for the `Object`?

Comment: it could be a long value or a string value

Comment: You want `Instant` for the date-time keys. I don't know `ObjectMapper`, so can't tell you how you obtain those, though.

Comment: I've tagged this a 'jackson', which seems to be the library this question is about.

Comment: Thanks, @TomHawtin-tackline. In that case, [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) might be a good part of the answer. As far as I understand, it handles `Instant` and `OffsetDateTIme`, the classes are the candidates for the datetimes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so dumb asking this question...

map.get("RequestsServed") is gonna give me a LinkedTreeMap. I just have to parse it into a HashMap of my choice.

serialising map.get("RequestsServed") to a json and parse the resultant value to HashMap will give me the required result easily.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a dummy class for testing purpose:

```
public class TempObject {
    private String date;
    private Double value;

    public TempObject(String date, Double value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is your solution:

```
// Initializing the Map (I'm using LinkedHashMap here for a reason)
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("RequestsServed", new TempObject("2019-06-28T00:00:00Z", 0.0));
map.put("PullRequests", new TempObject("2019-06-28T00:00:00Z", 0.1));

// Using Collectors.toMap() with mergeFunction (to handle duplicate keys)
Map<String, Object> result = map.values().stream().map(object -> (TempObject) object).collect(Collectors.toMap(TempObject::getDate, TempObject::getValue, (existingValue, newValue) -> newValue));

System.out.println(result); // printing the value of result map: {2019-06-28T00:00:00Z=0.1}
```

You can also parse this String value to `LocalDateTime`.